# colorizing commands vs arguments in output of shell

Tags: shell, make, colors

When working with make/cmake scripts you often have to use VERBOSE=1 and look at all the commands run. This is what I do a lot, and its utterly straining for someone just looking for the origin of commands.

We often have 30 lines of word wrapping args, and the command origin is obfuscated.

Is it possible to colorize commands in general so they stand out?  I need them to stand out from their arguments is all.

I can use either bash or zsh or any shell which supports this.  I just need to know if its possible to do this in general.

Comment: Sounds like it's the output of `make` or `cmake` or the commands they invoke to output those command lines before passing them to the shell that you want to colourise.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have the words 'warning' and 'error' colored so I do this in my shell startup file

```
make(){
    local subst
    subst+="s/error/\x1b[1;31m&\x1b[0m/g; "
    subst+="s/warning/\x1b[1;33m&\x1b[0m/g; "
    subst+="s/undefined reference/\x1b[1;35m&\x1b[0m/g; "
    # For debugging
    # echo "subst = '$subst'"
    (
        set -o pipefail
        CLICOLOR_FORCE=yes_please command make "$@" 2>&1 | sed --unbuffered "${subst}"
    )
}
```

With the right regexes instead of my `error`, `warning`, and `undefined reference`, you can probably get a pretty decent highlighting of your output going on.

Here are some details.

- You have to use `\x1b` in `sed` because it doesn't understand `\033`.
- `&` expands to the part of the line that was matched.
- `--unbuffered` is necessary otherwise your output will either come out in large chunks or in a single chunk once the whole make command finishes.
- `command` avoids recursively calling the `make` shell function.
- `"@"` forwards the arguments given to the `make` shell function to `command make`.  This will include `VERBOSE=1` and anything else.
- `CLICOLOR_FORCE` is to have the colored output from the Makefile that CMake generates which normally gets turned off if when the output is not a TTY (ex: a pipe).
- The subshell with `set -o pipefail` is because with a pipe, you normally get the return code of the last command in the pipeline.  Activating the option `pipefail` will cause the return code of the pipeline to be 0 if all commands returned 0, or the return code of the right-most command that returned a non-zero code (i.e. `(exit 8) | true | (exit 9) | true` would have a return code of 9).  The reason for the subshell is so that the `set -o pipefail` won't affect the user's shell.

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors for the color codes.

Normally, the output of a Makefile generated by CMake will have color for the `[ 42%] Building C object source_file.c.o` and such but this can be changed in the CMakeLists.txt with `set(CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE [ON|OFF])`.

Color also goes away if the output of `make` is not a tty (like `make | cat`.  You can force the color output in that case by setting the environment variable `CLICOLOR_FORCE=yes_please` (or any non-empty value).  However if `CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE` is off, `CLICOLOR_FORCE will have no effect.

If the project is not yours and `CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE` is off, then you can add some substitutions to the list to compensate.

Also note that `CLICOLOR_FORCE` is a variable that is inspected by other commands so putting `export CLICOLOR_FORCE=yessir` in your shell startup file will affect more things that you may want.  I don't do it.

Reference for `CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE.html

Comment: Note that your escape codes make assumptions that the output is connected to a terminal that recognises the ANSI escapes.  You'll get some other behaviour when connected to a different kind of terminal, or something other than a terminal (a pipe, perhaps).  It's generally better to use `tput` to find the appropriate control (if any) for the actual system in a portable manner.